# SQL - INSERT AND UPDATE Table from a Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert some data into a Temp Table(#temptable) and after inserting I would Like to perform Sum(amount) which matches the same ID and group by the cust name and the bill ID and I want to select the earliest date available in those matching ID. After all these Operations I would like to update the original table(billtable)

```
Bill ID   Amount  CUstName   Duedate

12         12.2     ABC        12222016
12         22.2     ABC        12112016
13         23.22    ABC        12102016

Bill ID   Amount  CUstName   Duedate

12         34.4     ABC        12112016
13         23.22    ABC        12102016
```

Comment: Update means, you want to update one row and delete all other rows with same `Bill ID`?

Comment: What do you have in your code so far?

Comment: @nCessity I would like to perform those operations on temp table and would like to insert the updates values to the bill table

Comment: @JacobH I performaed insert into #temptable ( Bill ID, Amount, CustName, Duedate) Values ( Bill ID,Amount, CustName,Duedate)INSERTINTO billtable SELECT BillID, SUM(Amount), CustName, MIN(InvoiceDate) GROUPBY BillID, CustName ;

Comment: Ok, now write your select statement to SUM your values from the #temptable. Then use that statement as the FROM clause of your update. SQL is much easier to write when you break each piece down to an individual query.

Comment: @JacobH, can you be please more specific? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you will need something like the below

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #t
End

 create table #t
(
billid varchar (50),
amount decimal,
cust varchar (50),
duedate datetime
)

insert into #t (billid,amount,cust,duedate) values ('12',12.2,'abc','20161222')
insert into #t (billid,amount,cust,duedate) values ('12',22.2,'abc','20161211')
insert into #t (billid,amount,cust,duedate) values ('13',23.22,'abc','20161210')
insert into #t (billid,amount,cust,duedate) values ('12',34.4,'abc','20161211')
insert into #t (billid,amount,cust,duedate) values ('13',23.22,'abc','20161210')

select billid,sum(amount),MIN(duedate)
from #t
group by billid
```